# Flow, dynamical systems

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

We have $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ Lipschitz and $x(\cdot; x_0 )$ is the unique solution of
$$x'(t)=f(x(t))$$ $$x(0)=x_0$$

Every solution of this ODE is global. Show, that $\Phi_t (x_0)=x(t;x_0)$ is  a flow with vectorfield $f$.

> I showed, that $\Phi$ is continuous differentiable (Picard–Lindelöf). I also understand that $\Phi (x_0)=x_0=id_{\mathbb{R}^N}$ for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^N$. But how can I show $\Phi_{t_1 +t_2}=\Phi_{t_1}\circ\Phi_{t_2}$. The composition is giving me trouble... This is equivalent to $x(t_1 +t_2;x_0)=x(t_1 ;x_0)\circ x(t_2 ;x_0)$. I tried to solve this in an example $x' =x, x(0)=x_0$, but this did not work at all because I get something like $x_0\exp(x_0\exp () ) $ Do I misunderstand this $\Phi$. It gets an initial value $z_0$ and maps it onto the unique solution $x(t; z_0)$

Comment: Can you use uniqueness of solution to ODE?

Comment: I think yes, because Picard-Lindelöff comes true.

Comment: Then fixing $t_2$, $x(t + t_2; x_0)$ and $x(t;x_0) \circ x(t_2; x_0)$ solves $x'(t) = f(x(t))$ with $x(0) = x(t_2;x_0)$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.

Comment: You have a mistake in the composition: $x(t_1 + t_2, x_0) = x(t_1, x(t_2, x_0))$ will be right, not your formula

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Phi_t (x_0)=x(t;x_0)$, the required composition property $\Phi_{t_1 +t_2}=\Phi_{t_1}\circ\Phi_{t_2}$ means: 
$$x(t_1+t_2;x_0) = x(t_1;x(t_2;x_0))\tag{1}$$
(as Evgeny said). Consider the left side as a function of $t_1$. It has the properties
$$\frac{d}{dt_1}x(t_1+t_2;x_0) = f(x(t_1+t_2;x_0)) \tag{2}$$
and 
$$x(t_1+t_2;x_0)\bigg|_{t_1=0} = x(t_2;x_0)\tag{3}$$
The properties (2)-(3) qualify $t_1\mapsto x(t_1+t_2;x_0)$ as a solution of the initial value problem (IVP) with initial value $x(t_2;x_0)$. But the right hand side of (1) solves exactly the same IVP. By uniqueness, both sides are the same.